# Mongo DB - Sync after primary node recovers from crash

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongoDB, while going through some tutorials I got a question in mind,

If I am using 3 replica nodes A,B,C . A is performing the role of primary and data is syncing to other 2 nodes after 2 seconds. Now primary node A fails and node B takes the role of primary.

After some time node A recovers and acts as a secondary.
Now what would happen to the data which is not sync(last 2 seconds data) when node A was acting as a primary ?

Basically my question is, does secondary node also sends data to primary node to be in sync, if yes in the above scenario when node B is acting as primary node and some document is deleted but the same data exists in node A and that data is updated in last 2 seconds what would happen?

Thanks and Best Regards,
Kitty

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you asked but should give you an idea,
[Mongo Replication Doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-primary/#id1)

[Mongodb rollback Doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/)

> In some circumstances, two nodes in a replica set may transiently believe that they are the primary, but at most, one of them will be able to complete writes with { w: "majority" } write concern. The node that can complete { w: "majority" } writes is the current primary, and the other node is a former primary that has not yet recognized its demotion, typically due to a network partition. When this occurs, clients that connect to the former primary may observe stale data despite having requested read preference primary, and new writes to the former primary will eventually roll back.
>
> A rollback reverts write operations on a former primary when the member rejoins its replica set after a failover. A rollback is necessary only if the primary had accepted write operations that the secondaries had not successfully replicated before the primary stepped down. When the primary rejoins the set as a secondary, it reverts, or “rolls back,” its write operations to maintain database consistency with the other members.
>
> MongoDB attempts to avoid rollbacks, which should be rare. When a rollback does occur, it is often the result of a network partition. Secondaries that can not keep up with the throughput of operations on the former primary, increase the size and impact of the rollback.
>
> A rollback does not occur if the write operations replicate to another member of the replica set before the primary steps down and if that member remains available and accessible to a majority of the replica set.